# Cómo convertir un entero a hora y minuto

Tags: php, mysql

¿Cómo convierto un entero que está almacenado en una tabla tipo varchar a hora y minutos?

El dato se guarda en MySQL de esta forma ejemplo: `1030` y necesito mostrarlo como `10:30 am`.

¿Se puede hacer una conversión en PHP o desde MySQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo usando la función `substr` de PHP.

Ejemplo:

```
$hora = substr('1030', 0, 2); // Tendrás 10
$minuto = substr('1030', 2, 2); // Tendrás 30
```

Luego pasamos a concatenar:

```
$nueva_hora = $hora.':'.$minuto;
```

Más información acerca de `substr` Aquí: http://php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php

Comment: $horacita = "830";
$mas = "0";
$union = $mas. $horacita;

$hora = substr($union, -4, -2);
$minuto = substr($union, -2);
$total = $hora.':'. $minuto;

echo $total;

Answer (score 4):

Con la funcion `date_create` y `date_format`

ejemplo: especificando `H:i:s` para que considere solamente la hora-min-seg

```
<?php

$date = date_create('1030');
echo date_format($date, 'H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 2):

Otra manera válida, usando un objeto [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php) y su factoría `createFromFormat`

```
$hora = DateTime::createFromFormat('Hi', '1030');
echo $hora->format('H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 2):

Se puede hacer también en el SELECT de MySQL, sin necesidad de pasar por PHP.

Muestro en la consulta 4 columnas: una con **el dato original** como vendría en la tabla... considerando que puede haber errores de digitación, otra con la **hora bien**, es decir, obligando a que tenga 4 dígitos, en el caso de valores como `130`, para ello se agrega un `0` a la izquierda usando [LPAD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad), otra con la **hora en formato AM/PM** y otra con la **hora en formato 24H**.

La consulta como ya he dicho, está pensada para corregir posibles valores erróneos y maneja también valores que estén introducidos en formato 24h, como `1330`.

Los resultados finales (columnas 3 y 4) son realmente datos del tipo `DATETIME`, obtenidos con la función [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) de MySQL. Y como son datos del tipo `DATETIME`, puedes mostrar los resultados como quieres, modificando simplemente los [especificadores de formato](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format). En este caso he usado `'%r'` y `'%H:%i'`, pero se pueden cambiar por cualquier otro válido :)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65d7d/50)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE horas
    (`id` int, `hora_string` varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO horas
    (`id`, `hora_string`)
VALUES
    (1, '1030'),
    (2, '130' ),
    (3, '1330' ),
    (3, '0130')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
  hora_string as hora_bien_o_mal,
  LPAD(hora_string,4,'0') as hora_bien,
  DATE_FORMAT(
    STR_TO_DATE(
      LPAD(hora_string,4,'0'),'%H%i'), '%r') as hora_AMPM,
  DATE_FORMAT(
    STR_TO_DATE(
      LPAD(hora_string,4,'0'),'%H%i'), '%H:%i') as hora_24
FROM horas
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65d7d/50/0)**:

> ```
> | hora_string | hora_bien |   hora_AMPM | hora_24 |
> |-------------|-----------|-------------|---------|
> |        1030 |      1030 | 10:30:00 AM |   10:30 |
> |         130 |      0130 | 01:30:00 AM |   01:30 |
> |        1330 |      1330 | 01:30:00 PM |   13:30 |
> |        0130 |      0130 | 01:30:00 AM |   01:30 |
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la forma más sencilla, rápida y válida sería esta:

```
substr_replace( $time, ':', -2, 0 );
```

Esto te convertirá lo siguiente:

- '10:30' cuando el valor sea 1030
- '09:30' cuando el valor sea 0930
- '9:30'  cuando el valor sea 930

Y, con esta salida, se puede mostrar con AM o PM de la siguiente manera:

```
date('h:i A', strtotime($time));
```

Un **ejemplo** completo:

```
$time = substr_replace( '930', ':', -2, 0 );
echo date('h:i A', strtotime($time));
```

Output:

```
09:30 AM
```